# Check the viewport size in ReactJs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to check if the viewport intersect the html tag element when resizing it. For this i created this component in my react js application:

```
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";
function isElementInViewport(el) {
  var rect = el?.getBoundingClientRect() || {};

  return rect.bottom >= 0 &&
      rect.right >= 0 &&
      rect.left <= (window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth) /* or $(window).width() */ &&
      rect.top <= (window.innerHeight || document.documentElement.clientHeight) /* or $(window).height() */;
}

export default function App() {
  React.useEffect(()=> {
    window.addEventListener('resize', (e) => {
      const el = document.getElementById('test');
      const a = isElementInViewport(el);
      console.log(a)
    });
  },[])
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div id='test' style={{backgroundColor: 'red', height: '200px', width: '200px'}}>test</div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/epic-goldwasser-ecotfg?file=/src/App.js:479-480

Resizing the viewport from the bottom to top my function did not give the `false` even if it intersect the  red element. 
 Question: How to fix my code to be able to check if the viewport intersect the red element?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to validate if neither of the edges of your element is touching the current view of the user. This also requires you to include the scroll position of the user.

Check out https://codesandbox.io/s/gallant-lichterman-wxnfrf?file=/src/App.js which checks if the red box is inside of the viewport or not.

Also, you do not need to put an ID to the element you would like to observe, have a look at https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref for more information on using references in React.